# What does "Convert into compound assignment" mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What does `Convert into compound assignment` for `p.y` mean in the context in this image?

[image]

The code seems to work just fine.

Wondering why that suggesting by the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Compound Assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator#compound-assignment).

> For a binary operator op, a compound assignment expression of the form:

```cs
x += y
```

is equivalent to

```cs
x = x + y
```

It simply makes your code more compact and (arguably) more readable.

Comment: Damnit, I'm so stupid, I thought it meant something needed to be done Unity way, and not a general programming thing.

Comment: @Patrioticcow No worry, we learn new simple things everyday ;)

Comment: @Patrioticcow for the next time - couldn't you just have tried? Simply click on that and see what it does to the code ^^